# What does the print function on the last line with :_^5 mean?

Tags: python

```
a = 10
b = 3 * (a-5)
c = b + (b//a) * a
print(f"a: {a}")
print("b: "+str(b))
print(f"c: {c:_^5}")
```

I would like to know what the "(f"c: {c:_^5}")" is doing

Comment: center alignment with underscore padding maybe? check https://pyformat.info/

Comment: Did you try running it? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

`f"c: {c:_^5}"` is an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), which can be used for formatting strings in Python 3.6+. It contains a replacement field `{c:_^5}`, which formats the value of `c` with center alignment, the width of 5 and `'_'` as the fill character.

Check [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for more info.